# Convert JSON from one format to another JSON format in java

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have to covert a specific JSON response and covert to some other format

For E.g. My input JSON is like

JSON1

```
[
    {
        "propertyId":10081,
        "roomId":0,
        "startDate":"2018-01-29T00:00:00",
        "endDate":"2018-01-30T00:00:00",
        "priority":1,
        "message":"Test it",
        "id":158,
        "dateModifiedUtc":null
    },
    {
        "propertyId":10081,
        "roomId":10021855,
        "startDate":"2018-01-29T00:00:00",
        "endDate":"2018-01-30T00:00:00",
        "priority":2,
        "message":"Check how it works",
        "id":159,
        "dateModifiedUtc":null
    },
    {
        "propertyId":10081,
        "roomId":10021855,
        "startDate":"2018-01-29T00:00:00",
        "endDate":"2018-01-30T00:00:00",
        "priority":2,
        "message":"Check how it works",
        "id":160,
        "dateModifiedUtc":null
    }
]
```

I need to replace some values for roomId and then convert json to below format and send it to some other endpoint

JSON2

```
{
    "sitenotification":[
        {
            "roomid":"10601",
            "priority":1,
            "startdate":"2017-08-10T15:50:52+03:00",
            "enddate":"2017-08-15T15:50:52+03:00",
            "sitemessage":"test"
        },
        {
            "roomid":"10601",
            "priority":1,
            "startdate":"2017-08-10T15:50:52+03:00",
            "enddate":"2017-08-15T15:50:52+03:00",
            "customermessage":"test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried doing this in couple of ways like Deserialization using jackson and mapping it to specific class like below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FatNotificationsAttributesDataModel {

    @JsonProperty("propertyId")
    public int propertyId;
    @JsonProperty("roomId")
    public int roomId;
    @JsonProperty("startDate")
    public String startDate;
    @JsonProperty("endDate")
    public String endDate;
    @JsonProperty("priority")
    public int priority;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int id;
    @JsonProperty("dateModifiedUtc")
    public String dateModifiedUtc;

}
```

and then again serialising it using a different class

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public class FinalDataModel {

    public int roomId;

    public String startDate;

    public String endDate;

    public int priority;

    public String message;

}
```

But somehow the conversion is not working. Do we have any better way to achieve this?

Comment: can you please clarify what doesn't work? is there any exception or output which differs from what you are expecting to get?

Comment: use gson, it will make your life easier

Comment: Your input isn't `Json` necessarily. Its an array of `Json` Elements. Try to deserialize into an `ArrayList<FatNotificationsAttributesDataModel>` and see if that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jackson deserialization json to java-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890129/jackson-deserialization-json-to-java-objects)

Comment: sorry my description was not good enough. I am able to deserialise JSON1 to list of by using something like this          
           List<JsonNode> attributes = node.findValues("attributes");
  pojo = mapper.convertValue(attributes, 
              FatNotificationsAttributesDataModel[].class); . But I am not sure how to get JSON2 from the list of objects , I am not very sure about the approach I have followed

Comment: may be something similar to JOLT API

Answer (score 3):

Use Jolt Convertor. Simplest, and esiest way to convert any JSON to any other JSON format.

https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using JSONObject and JSONArray

```
//Create a JSON array with your json string
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
//loop on your JSONArray elements
for (i=0, i<array.size(),i++) {
    //Get each separate object into a JSONObject
    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    //let say you want to modify id for example
    obj.put("id", 12345);
    //push the modifyed object into your new array
    newArray.put(obj);
}
//transform the array into a string
String json = newArray.toString();
```

Comment: I tried this solution but seems be having performance issues when we have bigger data sets

Comment: Obviously yes, there is probably better solutions/libraries out there for bigger data sets, ultimately you could use some sort of multithreading to achieve better performance but that's up to you. Remember that the solution i gave is based on what you was asking for.

Comment: Also, to be truely honest i tought it was for educationnal purpose at first, so i gave the basic answer when comming to JSON handling in Java ^^

Comment: thanks , I wouldn't need a solution ,probably I need just the best possible approach