# Get Data into Strings from API

Tags: java, json, api

I am new to subject API and I have a project for university. I managed to get informationen out of an Api, but now I want to get the exact informatationens into String to upload to Database later. Here is my code:

```
public class corona {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out
        .println(jsonGetRequest("https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/dcm4uXhiGIjVdJAzS/items?format=json&clean=1"));


  }

  private static String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    String text = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    return text;
  }

  public static String jsonGetRequest(String urlQueryString) {
    String json = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlQueryString);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
      connection.connect();
      InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
      json = streamToString(inStream); // input stream to string
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
  }
}
```

So so output looks like this right now: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvtoh.png)

How can I manged to get the data out field 76 for example?

Comment: What you need to do is first deserialize the JSON. Does this answer your question? [jackson deserialization json to java-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890129/jackson-deserialization-json-to-java-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to create model classes similar to the json response you are getting and convert the json response to model using any of the libraries.
For eg. using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeModel model = mapper.readValue("YOUR JSON STRING", SomeModel.class);
```

You can checkout [jackson-deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for moreexamples.